# what is the command line equivalent to using nautilus to connect to a samba drive?

Tags: command-line, samba

To connect to a samba shared drive on my network, I can use nautilus, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> and type in `smb://192.168.0.x`, enter my credentials and am able to connect and browse the drive.

How can I do the same thing from the command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the mount command `sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.x/<Share> /path/to/mount -o username=myuser,password=mypass`

`/path/to/mount` is an existing directory.

You may need to install `cifs-utils` but I think its included with Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: thanks for the info -- so behind the scenes, nautilus is mounting the drive.  So when nautilus does this, it's specifying /path/to/mount in ~/.gvfs?

Comment: I am not sure at all that nautilus uses cifs. Otherwise the workaround to this bug (fixed now) would have not worked: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1075923